# What is the difference between String[] data and String... data in java

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have tried with *data* and *data1* variables. It's always calling to **String ... data**.
So, what is the difference between **String[] data** and **String... data** in java.

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayTest arrayTest = new ArrayTest();
        // Option one
        String[] data = {"A", "B", "C"};
        // Option two
        String data1 = "A";
        arrayTest.test(data);


    }

    public void test(String[] ... data  ) {
        System.out.println("---From: String[] ... data---");

        for(String[] item: data) {

            for(String innerItem : item) {
                System.out.println(innerItem);
            }

        }
    }

    public void test(String ... data  ) {
        System.out.println("---From: String ... data---");
        for(String item: data) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `String[] ...` isn’t the same as `String[]`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Then my question is, **why both test methods are allowed at the same time?** and **why always calling to `String ...`  method?**

Comment: Is your question about `String[]... data` like in your code or about `String[] data` like in your title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `test(String... data)` you are passing an array of strings and in `test(String[]... data)` you are passing an array of arrays of strings. Check the updated code for illustration:

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayTest arrayTest = new ArrayTest();
        // Option one
        String[] data = { "A", "B", "C" };
        // Option two
        arrayTest.test(data);

        String[] data2 = { "D", "E" };
        arrayTest.test(data, data2);
    }

    public void test(String[]... data) {
        System.out.println("---From: String[] ... data---");

        for (String[] item : data) {

            for (String innerItem : item) {
                System.out.println(innerItem);
            }

        }
    }

    public void test(String... data) {
        System.out.println("---From: String ... data---");
        for (String item : data) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
---From: String ... data---
A
B
C
---From: String[] ... data---
A
B
C
D
E
```

In the presence of both versions of method signatures, JVM chooses the closest fit and that is why it goes to `test(String... data)` in case of `arrayTest.test(data)` while it goes to `test(String[]... data)` in case of `arrayTest.test(data, data2)`.

The program will still work if you remove the following definition but then JVM will be left with only one choice, which is to go to `test(String[]... data)` for both the calls.

```
public void test(String... data) {
    System.out.println("---From: String ... data---");
    for (String item : data) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Varargs (T...) arguments are packed into an array which is passed to the method at run time.
You have already answered your question with your own implementation:

For:

1) **public void test(String[] ... data)** -- data is packed as String[][]

2) **public void test(String ... data)**   -- data is packed as String[]

I strongly recommend the book: Java generics and collections - By Maurice Naftalin

Answer (score 0):

```
method(String... s) // fine
method(int i , String... s) // fine
method(String... s,int i) // not fine , ...s should be last or only parameter
method(String[] s) // fine
method(int i , String[] s) // fine
method(String[] s,int i) // fine
method(String s[]) // fine
method(String s...) // not fine can't put dot's after variable name
method(int[] i , String[] s) //fine
method(int... i , String...) // not fine, only one var arg is allowed
method(String... s) // takes any number of comma separated string also the array of String
method(String[] s) //only takes array of String but not comma separated string
```

At last -> (String[]... s) is equivalant to (String[][] s)

Answer (score 0):

***String ...*** will read a single sentence with multiple words.

***String[] ...*** will read a paragraph of multiple sentences.